# How to skip a schema change in Merge Replication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, replication, merge-replication

How can I skip a schema change in Merge Replication?

I added a column to a table as not null, but subscribers first have to create the column with null data so its failing to replicate. I already changed this column in origin as null, but the agent want to synchronize first change first.

Advice?

Comment: Which type of replication are you using?

Comment: @BrandonWilliams, this is a Merge replication

Comment: I have made a new snapshop. Can i just apply it to the subscriber?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can locate the schema change you would like to skip in the table [sysmergeschemachange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188042.aspx).  Another way to locate the schema change is to execute [sp_enumeratependingschemachanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189521.aspx):

```
EXEC sp_enumeratependingschemachanges 
    @publication = 'MyPublicationName'
```

Get the schemaversion from the result set and then skip the schema change by executing [sp_markpendingschemachange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173801.aspx).  For example, if the schemaversion is 22:

```
EXEC sp_markpendingschemachange 
    @publication = 'MyPublicationName',
    @schemaversion = 22
    @status = 'skipped'
```

Comment: You sir are amazing! Was stuck on this issue for two days. The procedure did the trick.

Comment: Yeah buddy, glad I could help.